# Packaging redis with windows installer file

Tags: redis

From the redis site, I only see linux installable file, is there a site where I can get the latest installer for windows, all my search led me to an outdated file. And I want to include redis in my installer exe file, how do I do that, files to include in my packaging file.

**P.S. I have gone through previous stackoverflow posts and none have been helpful.**

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not have official windows version.

Microsoft Open Tech group kept develop windows in the past, and latest version to 3.2, refer https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis.

Also, some other guys continued work of MicrosoftArchive, like https://github.com/tporadowski/redis , now have Redis 4.0.2 for Windows , you can have a try.